# How to convert A4 size invoice to POS size invoice in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, invoice, thermal-printer

I am working on a web app built in Flask that generates A4 size invoices`(using reportlab)`, but now I am required to convert those invoices to POS invoices *(which will print on thermal printer, like in the supermarkets)*. Also, A4 page has a fixed height but POS invoice should have a dynamic height according to the rows of data.

I have already tried adjusting the size values according to thermal paper but it just messes things up. I also tried exploring other options like `borb` and `escpos-python` but they do not appear to be good as `reportlab`

Is there any way to convert A4 size invoices to POS invoices? OR any way to generate POS invoices in `python` using `reportlab`?

I am using `python 3.7.9` and `macOS 12.1`

PS: POS thermal paper has a width of 80mm

Comment: As @K J commented, it is ridiculous to require printing on thermal rolls to look and be as artistic as printing on A4 cut sheet paper. Instead of doing something about the image or PDF of the processing result of reportlab, print it with text only, using the original data prepared for image creation. Only the corporate logo should be printed on the image.

Comment: Yup, that sounds good. I will try that. It might not be a good idea to convert the A4 size design into a 80mm wide receipt. Thanks to both of you for your comments.